# Identify Processed Files from Snowflake External Stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am loading csv files from Amazon S3 to Snowflake via a Snowflake External Stage pointing at Amazon S3 using the COPY command.

Is it possible to identify files that have already been processed by Snowflake?

I have explored listing from the external stage and querying the metadata for the external stage

Ideally, this data would output as a flag which I can query in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.LOAD_HISTORY` should contain relevant information on data loading.
Columns are `SCHEMA_NAME`, `FILE_NAME`, `TABLE_NAME`, `LAST_LOAD_TIME`, `STATUS`, `ROW_COUNT` etc.

[Documented here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/load_history.html).